# Possible to link .dll with .lib?

Tags: visual-c++, linker

Here's my dilemma: I'm attempting to create a `.dll` version of my project. This project uses the V8 and CURL libraries which are currently built as debug `.lib`s. I'd like to package all of them up in a single `DLL` that can be shared (I understand I need to alter my code with `__declspec(dllexport)` but that's a separate issue) to others.

Do I need to compile the V8 and CURL libraries as DLLs then somehow wrap them up in my own DLL?

Comment: No, just link the static v8 and curl .libs so their code gets included in your dll.

Comment: When I do that, building my project with /MDd /DLL, I get errors saying 'LIBCMTD.lib(invarg.obj) : error LNK2005: __invalid_parameter already defined in MSVCRTD.lib(MSVCR90D.dll)' This leads me to believe that I DO need to compile V8 and CURL as DLLs. Any suggestions?

Comment: No, you just need to recompile those static libs with the same compiler settings.  /MD is required for them as well, mixing CRT versions is not supported.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have a `.lib` with no `.dll` for the CURL libraries, then they are most certainly static libraries. When you link them to your DLL, the code from these libraries is linked into your DLL.

Answer (score 0):

I've generally had to include the source for the dependencies (in your case both V8 and CURL) in my project and build that way to get them completely incorporated without extra headaches.

If you have libs and you link to those you SHOULD get them merged though.